# Reverse Linklist showing strange behaviour

Tags: c, linked-list

### Driver code:-

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
struct node * head=NULL;
int main()
{
    struct node *newhead;
    struct node *newhead1;
    //Inserting 5 nodes;
    inset_end(5);
    inset_end(1);
    inset_end(0);
    inset_end(1);
    inset_end(5);
    print_data();
    //print
    newhead=midnode();
    //printf("%d ",newhead->data);
//  new->next=0;
    newhead1=reverse(newhead);
    //printf("%d ",isPallindrome(newhead));
    

return 0;
```

}

### Reverse function definition

```
struct node * reverse(struct node *newhead)
{
    struct node *prev=NULL;
    struct node *cur=newhead;
    struct node *next=NULL;
    while(cur!=NULL)
    {
        next=newhead;
        cur->next=prev;
        prev=cur;
        cur=next;
    }
    newhead=prev;   
    return newhead; 
}
```

### print function defination

```
void print_data()
{
    struct node *copyhead=head;
    printf("Printing the data of nodes");
    
    while(copyhead!=NULL)
    {
    printf("%d ",copyhead->data);
    copyhead=copyhead->next;    
    }
}
```

### Midnode function defination

```
struct node * midnode()
{
    struct node *slowpointer=head;
    struct node *fastpointer=head;
    
    while(fastpointer->next!=0)
    {
        slowpointer=slowpointer->next;
        fastpointer=fastpointer->next->next;    
    }
    return slowpointer->next;
}
```

After running this program if i am running till midnode function it works fine but if i am trying to reverse the node from the middle using reverse function the print_data() function is also not executing.Has anyone faced similar issue.I am using gcc compiler.

### Output:-

1.till midnode function()
Printing the data of nodes 5 1 0 1 5

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: Yes sure i will keep in mind minimal approach

Comment: i think the issue is with reverse function coz other functions are working properly

Comment: At no point in your `reverse()` function does `struct node *next` point to `cur->next`.

Comment: So I suppose there is no more question?

Comment: @trincot no no more question.I got the answer